# How to remove class using jQuery when the value is called from a custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am building a custom field for a user to allow custom sales badge in a WooCommerce powered site. The field is created and the value is also being echoed on the shop archive page, displaying the user input sales-badge value. But there is one problem. The default sale badge is also showing. How I can remove this?

[image]

This is how I am echoing the value

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'ac_wc_show_custom_fields', 20); 

    function ac_wc_show_custom_fields(){
        global $post;
        if (get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ac_custom_badge', true )!==''){
            echo '<div class="ac-loop-cus-badge">' .get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ac_custom_badge', true ) . '</div>';

        }
    }
```

I then tried this and it's working but it's adding the property `display:none` to all `.onsale` class in the site

```
    function ac_wc_show_custom_fields(){
            global $post;
            if (get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ac_custom_badge', true )!==''){
                echo '<div class="ac-loop-cus-badge">' .get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ac_custom_badge', true ) . '</div>';
echo '<style>.onsale{display:none;}</style>';

            }
        }
```

I just want to apply the css or any other jQuery method to remove the `.onsale` span/class only when the custom field of sales badge retrieved. Hope I made sense.

Thanks

**Addendum**

I also tried to override the sales template using this function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );

function custom_woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash() {
     global $post;

     if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ac_custom_badge', true)) {
          wc_get_template( 'files/sale-flash.php' );

     }
}
```

But I end up with two markeups for the sales. Please see the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For doing this in JavaScript (w/ jQuery), if you run this at the bottom of the page, I think you'll get what you are after.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ac-loop-cus-badge").removeClass("onsale");
</script>
```

Documentation for what how all this works can be found at [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

If you need to apply this only to one page, or container div, you could add a class to your shop archive page. This would prevent it from removing the `onsale` class for other pages or divs.

```
<div class="shop-archive-page"> 
    <!-- page contents do here-->
    <img class="ac-loop-cus-badge"></img>
    <!-- more page contents do here-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".shop-archive-page .ac-loop-cus-badge").removeClass("onsale");
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
For an example using `:contains` where Product A is in the DOM below its product image you could use the following.

```js
$(".image-container span:contains('Product A')").parent().find(".ac-loop-cus-badge").removeClass("onsale");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <i class="ac-loop-cus-badge onsale">IMAGE WOULD BE HERE</i>
  <br />
  <span class="product-description">This is Product A, it's on sale right now!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, this does not help as those are called via hooks on the archive page and when I removeclass, it applies all over since the condition is not being matched. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Sorry @Ayanize I'm not following. So what is different between the html tags that have the `ac-loop-cus-badge` class, and those with the `ac-loop-cus-badge` that don't need the `onsale` class removed? Is it a certain sub-set of the page, or some other business rule that you could perhaps further explain?

Comment: Yes, I just want to apply css (hide the sale badge) on those product where the custom field value is called, not on all the products even though they have the sales in place. In short, add custom badge on Product A, hide default badge icon on Product A not on other products.

Comment: So right now, I'm guessing Product A doesn't have a css class (i.e., `span="product-a"`. Can you identify Product A by the text description of the product? See link [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) .

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, this does not help either. No Product A or any other product does not have any unique text which contains() jQuery can pick and apply other rules.